# How do I end the story when score 100 reached? inform 7

Tags: inform7

This code isn't working for me:

```
if score is 100:
    end the story saying "Congratulations you have achieved a perfect score!".
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this:

```
"Scoring" by Lynn

Use scoring. The maximum score is 100.

Carry out jumping: increase score by 20.

Every turn when score >= maximum score:
  end the story finally saying "Congratulations!".

The Lab is a room.
```